# Indefinite integral with exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, integration

This problem was anonymously posted on Quora.

$$\int\frac{e^x}{1+x^2}dx$$

I tried the trigonometric substitution $$x^2=\tan (x) $$ and the hyperbolic functions $$\sinh(x)+\cosh(x)=e^x,$$ but I haven't found anything so far.
We are going to learn this in the second semester, but I ask this so that the person who initially posted it could see it since I can't help him/her. I wanted to post the direct link, but I can't find it in my history.

Comment: Mathematica says this cannot be expressed as an elementary function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral)$$\operatorname{Ei}(x):=-\int_{-x}^\infty\frac{e^{-t}}{t}dt=\int_{-\infty}^x\frac{e^u}{u}du$$is a non-elementary special function satisfying $\frac{e^x}{x-a}=e^a\operatorname{Ei}^\prime(x-a)$ so$$\int\frac{e^x}{1+x^2}dx=\frac{1}{2i}\int\left(\frac{e^x}{x-i}-\frac{e^x}{x+i}\right)dx=\frac{1}{2i}\left(e^i\operatorname{Ei}(x-i)-e^{-i}\operatorname{Ei}(x+i)\right)+C.$$